# How do I catch an unhandled sql connection exception when using structuremap and EF in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, dependency-injection, exception

Ok so I'm trying to install a web application on server at another facility within our company and I've run into a problem that I'm trying to diagnose.  I'm getting the infamous DI error message "requires a parameterless constructor", which is what is caught in the Application_Error on Global.asax.

I'm unable to debug remotely right now, so I'd like to rig together some basic but more detailed exception handling that can help me see what the real exception is.  Is there anything quick and easy I can to do get more details on the Application_Error exception?

So to test this out myself, I changed my connection string to have a bad password.  This throws a SqlException "Login failed for user 'xxxxxxxx'".  I am not currently doing basically any exception handling throughout the project since I haven't really gotten to that yet.  I'm trying to see how I can some how transport my exceptions from my data/service projects up to the web project so I can at least see some more detail from within the browser as I try to trouble shoot the installation.

The first database call pretty much has a call stack like so
StructureMap DoGetInstance -> ServiceLayer UserAuthService -> DataLayer UserRepo

I've tried wrapping my data layer method in a try/catch and rethrowing the SqlException.  I've then wrapped my ServiceLayer in another try/catch and have managed to catch that exception.  Its between the ServiceLayer and the DI resolver where I'm unable to catch it, so when debugging I get an error saying there is an unhandled exception at this point.  For testing, I tried wrapping this in a try/catch but it still goes unhandled.

So the result is what ends up as the last exception caught in Application_Error is that the dependency for my controller could not be found / controller could not be constructed.

```
protected override object DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, string key) {
        //IContainer container = (CurrentNestedContainer ?? Container);
        IContainer container = Container;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            try
            {
                    return serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface
                        ? container.TryGetInstance(serviceType)
                        : container.GetInstance(serviceType);

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (EntityException ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return container.GetInstance(serviceType, key);
    }
```

I'd appreciate any tips here.  I'm really not looking to build out a major exception handling or logging solution at this time, it's really not that kind of project yet.  As you can tell I don't have a lot of experience with exception handling really.  I don't know what the error is, so breaking the connection string was just a test to try and get deeper exceptions up to the surface.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. _On a completely unrelated front, feel free to remove the above `catch` blocks and `throw` calls - they don't achieve anything._

Comment: Oh yeah those aren't staying, just trying to get a better understanding.
I can certainly try putting a simple example together later on, I should throw it up on github I suppose?

Comment: Please put the code here in your question. Keep it as small as possible.